# Use VBA to multiply matrices and save results in text file

Tags: vba, excel

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me some help with this.

I am quite familiar with vba and I can write simple code and also customise code from others. I have written /customised/copied several pieces of vba code to do the following (where copied source is acknowledged):

1. Select 2 different csv files which represent 2 matrixes of same columns and same rows.
2. Multiply each respective cells from the matrices.
3. Return results.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to be able to get this to run. 
Any idea what I have not done correctly? 
Please see the code below. Thanks so much. 
**Code changed from previous version**

```
Public Sub doIt()
    Dim sourceFile As String
    Dim destinationFile As String
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim sourceFile2 As String
    Dim datarain As Variant

    sourceFile = "C:\file1.csv"
    sourceFile2 = "C:\file2.csv"
    destinationFile = "C:\file3.txt"
    data = getDataFromFile(sourceFile, ",")
    datarain = getDataFromFile(sourceFile2, ",")
    If Not isArrayEmpty(data) Then
       result = MMULT2_FUNC(data, datarain)
       writeToCsv result, destinationFile, ","
    Else
       MsgBox ("Empty file")
    End If
End Sub

Function MMULT2_FUNC(ByRef ADATA_RNG As Variant, _
ByRef BDATA_RNG As Variant)

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

Dim ANROWS As Long
Dim BNROWS As Long

Dim ANCOLUMNS As Long
Dim BNCOLUMNS As Long

Dim ADATA_MATRIX As Variant
Dim BDATA_MATRIX As Variant

Dim TEMP_MATRIX As Variant

On Error GoTo ERROR_LABEL

ADATA_MATRIX = ADATA_RNG
BDATA_MATRIX = BDATA_RNG

ANROWS = UBound(ADATA_MATRIX, 1)
BNROWS = UBound(BDATA_MATRIX, 1)

ANCOLUMNS = UBound(ADATA_MATRIX, 2)
BNCOLUMNS = UBound(BDATA_MATRIX, 2)

If ANCOLUMNS <> BNROWS Then: GoTo ERROR_LABEL

ReDim TEMP_MATRIX(1 To ANROWS, 1 To BNCOLUMNS)

For i = 1 To ANROWS
    For j = 1 To BNCOLUMNS
        TEMP_MATRIX(i, j) = 0
        For k = 1 To ANCOLUMNS
            TEMP_MATRIX(i, j) = TEMP_MATRIX(i, j) + ADATA_MATRIX(i, k) * _
                                BDATA_MATRIX(k, j)
        Next k
    Next j
Next i

MMULT2_FUNC = TEMP_MATRIX

Exit Function
ERROR_LABEL:
MMULT2_FUNC = Err.Number
End Function


Public Sub writeToCsv(parData As Variant, parFileName As String, parDelimiter As String)

    If getArrayNumberOfDimensions(parData) <> 2 Then Exit Sub

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim FileNum As Long
    Dim locLine As String
    Dim locCsvString As String

    FileNum = FreeFile
    If Dir(parFileName) <> "" Then Kill (parFileName)
    Open parFileName For Binary Lock Read Write As #FileNum

    For i = LBound(parData, 1) To UBound(parData, 1)
      locLine = ""
      For j = LBound(parData, 2) To UBound(parData, 2)
        If IsError(parData(i, j)) Then
          locLine = locLine & "#N/A" & parDelimiter
        Else
          locLine = locLine & parData(i, j) & parDelimiter
        End If
      Next j
      locLine = Left(locLine, Len(locLine) - 1)
      If i <> UBound(parData, 1) Then locLine = locLine & vbCrLf
      Put #FileNum, , locLine
    Next i

error_handler:
    Close #FileNum

End Sub

Public Function isArrayEmpty(parArray As Variant) As Boolean
'Returns false if not an array or dynamic array that has not been initialised (ReDim) or has been erased (Erase)

  If IsArray(parArray) = False Then isArrayEmpty = True
  On Error Resume Next
  If UBound(parArray) < LBound(parArray) Then isArrayEmpty = True: Exit Function Else: isArrayEmpty = False

End Function

Public Function getArrayNumberOfDimensions(parArray As Variant) As Long
'Returns the number of dimension of an array - 0 for an empty array.

    Dim i As Long
    Dim errorCheck As Long

    If isArrayEmpty(parArray) Then Exit Function 'returns 0

    On Error GoTo FinalDimension
    'Visual Basic for Applications arrays can have up to 60000 dimensions
    For i = 1 To 60001
        errorCheck = LBound(parArray, i)
    Next i

    'Not supposed to happen
    getArrayNumberOfDimensions = 0
    Exit Function

FinalDimension:
    getArrayNumberOfDimensions = i - 1

End Function

Private Function getDataFromFile(parFileName As String, parDelimiter As String, Optional parExcludeCharacter As String = "") As Variant
'parFileName is supposed to be a delimited file (csv...)
'parDelimiter is the delimiter, "," for example in a comma delimited file
'Returns an empty array if file is empty or can't be opened
'number of columns based on the line with the largest number of columns, not on the first line
'parExcludeCharacter: sometimes csv files have quotes around strings: "XXX" - if parExcludeCharacter = """" then removes the quotes


  Dim locLinesList() As Variant
  Dim locData As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim locNumRows As Long
  Dim locNumCols As Long
  Dim fso As Variant
  Dim ts As Variant
  Const REDIM_STEP = 10000

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  On Error GoTo error_open_file
  Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(parFileName)
  On Error GoTo unhandled_error

  'Counts the number of lines and the largest number of columns
  ReDim locLinesList(1 To 1) As Variant
  i = 0
  Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
    If i Mod REDIM_STEP = 0 Then
      ReDim Preserve locLinesList(1 To UBound(locLinesList, 1) + REDIM_STEP) As Variant
    End If
    locLinesList(i + 1) = Split(ts.ReadLine, parDelimiter)
    j = UBound(locLinesList(i + 1), 1) 'number of columns
    If locNumCols < j Then locNumCols = j
    If j = 13 Then
      j = j
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Loop

  ts.Close

  locNumRows = i

  If locNumRows = 0 Then Exit Function 'Empty file

  ReDim locData(1 To locNumRows, 1 To locNumCols + 1) As Variant

  'Copies the file into an array
  If parExcludeCharacter <> "" Then

    For i = 1 To locNumRows
      For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
        If Left(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
          If Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
            locLinesList(i)(j) = Mid(locLinesList(i)(j), 2, Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 2)       'If locTempArray = "", Mid returns ""
          Else
            locLinesList(i)(j) = Right(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
          End If
        ElseIf Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
          locLinesList(i)(j) = Left(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
        End If
        locData(i, j + 1) = locLinesList(i)(j)
      Next j
    Next i

  Else

    For i = 1 To locNumRows
      For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
        locData(i, j + 1) = locLinesList(i)(j)
      Next j
    Next i

  End If

  getDataFromFile = locData

  Exit Function

error_open_file:                 'returns empty variant
unhandled_error:                 'returns empty variant

End Function
```

Comment: `Unfortunately I cannot seem to be able to get this to run` Then please try again. Debug and try to isolate the problem and update your question with any error messages. SO is not a debugging service.

Comment: My version is actually running. My problem is that it does not print the output file.

Comment: See, that should go in the question! It doesn't say anywhere what the problem is. So your question amounts to _help me debug this code_... :)

Comment: `My problem is that it does not print the output file` - so what _does_ it do? Debug. Share the result.

Comment: Yeah, true, sorry. This is actually my problem :)

Comment: It basically runs for 10 seconds and then stops, as if it has been completed. Actually I simplified the code and edited my original post(please see above) but it still does the same thing. I had almost the same code on another spreadsheet(except for the function MMULT2_FUNC, in the place of which was another function) and it worked fine. I think I have probably made a mistake with calling the results to the csv file.

Comment: While I am looking at your code ... have you made sure you have WRITE permissions to C:\ ? on Win7 for instance this is not a given ...

Comment: @Mary have you stepped into the macro using `F8` and then run it one step at a time ? This will help to find a logic error as you can see each step executing

Comment: @Whytheq: Thanks, just did that and worked out what the problem was. I posted it in the answer:).

Answer (score 0):

Despite my personal impression that your code can be improved in some instances, it syntactically executes here with no problem (on small matrices).

My test data

```
1,2,3       2,3,4      20,26,32
2,3,4   X   3,4,5  =   29,38,47
3,4,5       4,5,6      38,50,62
```

The result is neatly written to a CSV.

Only obvious problem (here on Win 7 !) is that `Sub writeToCsv -> Open parFileName` ... fails due to lack of write permissions into the root directory. This might be not a problem on XP.

On a different token, I have the impression the code can be improved, but I may not understand the rationale behind some parts of your code.

examples

```
Function MMULT2_FUNC(ByRef ADATA_RNG As Variant, ByRef BDATA_RNG As Variant) ' missing type of result

Private Function getDataFromFile(...)
...
If j = 13 Then
    j = j
End If ' whow ... if j <> 13 then j again equals j ;-)
```

finding upper and lower bounds of the matrices on input as well as on output could be simplified by large ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I know my code is not perfect, I am trying to improve slowly but steadily. Thanks for your comments, it made me think that probably mine was not working because it was not same column and row numbers. So managed to work out the problem:)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. The reason why my code was not printing results was that I had this:`If ANCOLUMNS <> BNROWS Then: GoTo ERROR_LABEL`. At the same time, I was using two matrices of 70*120, so it constantly exited the function as I had programmed it to do!!Corrected it all and worked fine. Thanks a lot for your help